# Powershell `echo -e "1\n2\n3" | tail -n1` equivalent

Tags: powershell

There are countless examples about how to get tail for file content, but there is no for pipes.

Is there any way to get last line from pipe ?

I have long chain of piped commands and I want last 1 line only.

Comment: Do you mean the last object that is send through the pipe? `$input | Select-Object -Last 1` does that.

Comment: this seems to work @ManuelBatsching but missing one thing - `| Select -ExpandProperty propname`, thanks :)

Comment: I think you mean `echo -e "1\n2\n3"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the last object, that is send through the pipe, `Select-Object` can do that for you:

```bsh
$input | Select-Object -Last 1
```

If you are only interested in one particular property of this object, you can expand this property in the same statement:

```bsh
[pscustomobject]@{propname = 'foo'},[pscustomobject]@{propname = 'bar'} | 
    Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty propname
```

Answer (score 0):

Or -1 is the last element of an array.

```
(echo 1 2 3)[-1]

3
```